# using macro to expand subdocuments

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a word document (word 2013) made of sub-documents.

To produce the final doc, I have to :

> - View->Outline

Then, click on 'Expand subdocument' and close the outline view via 'Close outline view' button.

I am trying to write a macro that does this automatically (using the macro recorder in first place to find the right commands).
But I fail to have the equivalent of 'Close outline view'.

```
ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.Type = wdOutlineView
ActiveDocument.Subdocuments.Expanded = True
```

I have then added the following statement, hoping it will close the outline view, but not:

```
ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.Type = wdNormalView
```

Using the hint provided by [bmgh1985](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2574177/bmgh1985), I have modified this last statement by :

```
ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.Type = 3
```

But Word hangs up : the expansion of `Subdocument` is an asynchronous processing (triggered by the modification of the Expanded property), word is expanding the `Subdocument`while the view is reverted back to the normal one.

Is there a way to wait for the end of the expansion of `Subdocument`? (I have tried to use a timer, and a big loop, but no way....)

Comment: Have you tried creating a variable to get the initial state of `ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.Type` and then setting it back to the saved variable once completed?

Comment: As I recall, a SubDocument's Locked property is only False if it's expanded? Have you tried checking for that change in a loop?

Comment: I did a couple of experiment, but still no good outcomes : to get the subdocument expanded, I have to set the Expanded property to True. But then I do not know how to wait the completion of the expansion of all subdocuments before moving to the next vba statement. I have tried to implementent a timer -  Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:20")) - but it seems  only valid for Excel vba.

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing the

```
 ActiveDocument.Subdocuments.Expanded = True
```

With

```
Do While ActiveDocument.Subdocuments.Expanded = False
    ActiveDocument.Subdocuments.Expanded = True
Loop
```

Which will then keep the script at that pint until the `Expanded = True`
Then to go back to normal document viewing use:

`ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.Type = wdPrintView`

instead of

`ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.Type = 3`

EDITED:

SO, what I found is that running your original script, it took a while for word to catch up with the number of pages in the document, in my test case it was expanding 10 Subdocuments of 24 pages each and each document had text, tables and pictures.

I added a Loop after the Expanding of the Subdocuments which seemed to have sorted out the delayed page number updating.

Using the Macro Recorder I also found another way to Toggle the Expanded Subdocuments without having to go via the OutLine View.

```
Sub Macro2()
    'Toggles the Expanded without going view the Outline View
    ActiveDocument.Subdocuments.Expanded = Not ActiveDocument.Subdocuments.Expanded

    i = 1
    Do Until i = TotPages
        'Setting i to Total Number of Pages
        i = Selection.Information(wdNumberOfPagesInDocument)
        'Setting TotPages to Total Number of Pages
        TotPages = Selection.Information(wdNumberOfPagesInDocument)
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Thx for your help - but it is still failing : Word seems stuck now.

Comment: Check that you don't have other instances  of word open which are running  in the background. This can be view via the TaskManager

Comment: @PierreG. how many `Subdocuments` are there in your document and approximately how many pages per doc.

Comment: unfortunately it does not work (after few fixes in your code) : for some reason the expansion does not take place, and the loop ends after 1 iteration since TotPages does not reach the expected value (which should be around 240p). but thx for your support and you gave me additional knowledge I do not have.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for the ideas in this thread. However it wasn't expanding the subdocuments that was causing the problem. It's changing the view that happens asynchronously, and unless you've waited for that to complete (DoEvents), the subdocument expansion doesn't work. The following code works for me in Word 2010.

```
Sub SetupMasterForEditing()                                                                                                                             
'                                                                                                                                                       
' The document comes up in a default mode with subdocuments locked. Change it back.                                                
'                                                                                                                                                       
    ChangeView (wdOutlineView)                                                                                                                          
    ActiveDocument.Subdocuments.Expanded = True                                                                                                         
    ChangeView (wdPrintView)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
End Sub 

Sub ChangeView(View As Integer)                                                                                                                         
' Change to view View - see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836365.aspx for values                                                    
    ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.Type = View                                                                                                            
    DoEvents                                                                                                                                   
End Sub
```

Comment: Oops - this still sometimes fails with a run-time error if run with a new instance of Word. Kludge is to click 'OK' and run it again!

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to accomplish the same thing and the following works for me (Office 2007):

```
Sub ExpandAll()
  ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.View.Type = wdMasterView

  If ActiveDocument.Subdocuments.Count >= 1 Then
    ActiveDocument.Subdocuments.Expanded = True
  End If

  ' Unlink
  ActiveDocument.Subdocuments(1).Delete
End Sub
```

It is strange. I originally tried wdOutlineView but I kept getting errors. When I switched to wdMasterView it suddenly worked AND went to Outline View. I have no idea why.

The last line unlinks the subdocuments from the master. The weird thing is that I don't know why it works. I was originally going to iterate through the subdocuments collection to delete each one but for some reason, just deleting the first one already unlinks them all.